# Visual Studio 2012 Attach to process dialog does not have Show Processes from all sessions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Pro on Windows 8 Pro.

What I want to do is attach to w3wp so I can debug a website but w3wp isn't showing in the process list.

In every example, I can find it shows both Show processes from other users and Show processes from all sessions ticked.

However when I launch the Attach To Process dialog, I don't have the  Show processes from other sessions tick box.

Anybody please let me know how I can get that tick box to appear?

I've tried running VS as administrator but it makes no difference.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio?

Comment: I thought I had put that.  It's Pro.

Answer (score 2):

On the project's properties, the web tab try using local IIS web server and uncheck use IIS Express

Comment: IIS is already set as the web server.  If I load VS with a non webserver project I still don't get that tick box.

Comment: If I go to command prompt and execute iisreset, w3wp disappears as you would expect. If I view the project in browser with the IIS express checkbox ticked, it runs on a cassini port and I can attach to process by looking for the corresponding port number, but w3wp is still not visible. Then if then I deselect the IIS express checkbox and view in browser, w3wp appears and I can attach to it.