# How to debug ASP site without port number on VS 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I'm trying to debug an ASP.NET 4.0 web site using Visual Studio Express 2012. I've configured the project settings to use the local IIS web server which was installed with VS. I need to use IIS so that urlrewritingnet will work.

I need to run the site locally without a port number. Currently it runs as `http://localhost:4652/` which breaks some of the routines since they reference Request.Url.Host. This results in attempts to access resources using `http://localhost/`.

There is a lot of code to this site and it would be extremely easier and quicker (I think) to just configure my local debug to run on localhost instead of localhost:4652. Is there a way of doing this?

Since it's IIS Express installed with VS there is no configuration manager for IIS. When I click PROJECT -> mysite Properties and change the Project Url (under Use Local IIS Web Server) to `http://localhost/` I get a warning that reads:

The local IIS Express URL `http://localhost/` specified for Web project mysite has not been configured. To keep these settings you need to configure the virtual directory. Would you like to create the virtual directory now?

When I click on Yes, I get another dialog box saying:

Unable to create the virtual directory `http://localhost/`

Does anyone know if this should or should not work and if it can work, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to "user/documents/iisexpress/config" then open applicationhost with notepad or other relevant editor then go find "bindings" then change the value of bindingInformation into "*:80:localhost". Done

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple. You need to attach the IIS process to the visual studio and browse the website.

Below article guides to achieve this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37182/Debug-your-ASP-NET-Application-while-Hosted-on-IIS

Its always a good practice to do a unit test of web apps to local iis while developing.

Comment: I'm not seeing an `Attach to Process` under the DEBUG menu (or any others). Should I find this in VS 2012 Express? Something I was wondering... What about Request.Url.Authority - if the site runs on port 80 it doesn't seem to output :80, but when running locally it will output :4652. Can I rely on this? I'm wondering if I could just replace the Request.Url.Host code with Request.Url.Authority instead?

Comment: I am not using Vs 2k12 . as per this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx it is available. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234609/visual-studio-2012-attach-to-process-dialog-does-not-have-show-processes-from-al I think it may help you